# Keyup affect the typing in textbox in browser when i send the request. are this possible to stop affect?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, usability

in a webpage i have a textbox where user type something and get the result as change the content through ajax request response.

because if i type faster then response maybe late then typing so it' make typing speed slow.

are this possible to stop affect these kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to guard against this i usually do something like:

```
var to = null;
$('input').keyup(function()
{
    if(to!=null)
    {
        clearTimeout(to);
        to = null;
    }
    to = setTimeout(function()
                    {
                       // do my stuff here
                       to = null;
                    },200); 
});
```

it waits 200 milliseconds after the last keyup before making the request, if a new keyup occurs the timeout is reset.

Comment: there is no way to guarantee that the AJAX response would have returned within that time.

Comment: @danny, that is true, but using this method wont make the request until the person pauses typing reducing the number of requests made.  This will reduce the problems that may occur.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you type something in your textbox your AJAX request will fire off.  Lock or disable the textbox to prevent typing.  Once the AJAX request comes back from the server your callback function should re-enable the textbox.  This will ensure that the typing never gets "ahead" of the AJAX responses.

For handling niceness you would show an animation over the locked textbox.